# Согласные двойные или удвоенные?

Tags: терминология, удвоенные-буквы, согласные

Встречаются два варианта: "двойные согласные" и "удвоенные согласные". Возможно, оба верны? Это синонимы? Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта верны. Более того, думаю, выражения "двойные согласные" и "удвоенные согласные" всегда взаимозаменяемы. В учебниках, справочниках, пособиях и т.п. они зачастую равноправно используются в одном тексте. Вот, например, цитата из Розенталя:

> Двойные (удвоенные) согласные всегда обозначают один звук, хотя изображаются двумя буквами.

Answer (score 2):

**Двойные согласные** — более частотный вариант, он использовался в Правилах 1956 года (там нет термина ***удвоенный***). Правила Розенталя и Лопатина в современной редакции также используют название ***двойные согласные*** (***двойное Н***).

И это правильно, так как здесь обозначен **сам факт** наличия двойной согласной в слове.

Слово ***удвоенный*** также применяется, оно есть в словаре (***удвоенное Н***). Но встречается это слово реже, и, возможно, используется **в качестве синонима** в тексте, чтобы избежать повторения одного и того же термина.

Семантика слова ***удвоенный*** связана с глаголом ***удвоить*** (удвоение же происходит на стыке морфе), поэтому  обычно этот термин **не используется в справочниках в качестве общего понятия.**